# When we open one accordion other one should close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I have to close the accordion when another one is open.I have to display only one accordion to open at a time.
Currently, the accordion allows you to have multiple panels open at one time. If I open one tab, and then open another tab, both tabs will be open at the same time. I have to display only one.  Would you help me in this?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".expand").on( "click", function() {

    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");
    
    if($expand.text() == "+") {
      $expand.text("-");
    } else {
      $expand.text("+");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#integration-list {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#integration-list ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #555;
}
#integration-list ul > li {
    list-style: none;
/*    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;*/
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#integration-list ul > li > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.expand {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expand h2{
    font-size: 28px;
}
#sup{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
}
.detail {
    margin: 0 34px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 22px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
}

.detail h2{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
.right-arrow {
/*    margin-top: 12px;*/
    margin:0 20px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.icon {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

<div id="integration-list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>
        </li>
        
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>        
     </li>


    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using simple `.not()` you can achieve this.** When one accordion is opened the other needs to `slideUp()` and also the sign of other needs to be `'+'`

> Below is the working code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".expand").on( "click", function() {
  var x = $(this).next();
    $('.detail').not(x).slideUp();
   
    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");
    
    if($expand.text() == "+") {
      $expand.text("-");
      $('.right-arrow').not($expand).text("+");
    } else {
      $expand.text("+");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#integration-list {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#integration-list ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #555;
}
#integration-list ul > li {
    list-style: none;
/*    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;*/
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#integration-list ul > li > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.expand {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expand h2{
    font-size: 28px;
}
#sup{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
}
.detail {
    margin: 0 34px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 22px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
}

.detail h2{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
.right-arrow {
/*    margin-top: 12px;*/
    margin:0 20px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.icon {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

<div id="integration-list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>
        </li>
        
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>        
     </li>


    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Sahil Working perfectly for me. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 2):

Just hide all `.details` first and set the text of all `.right-arrow` to "+".

EDIT:

As the comment suggested, I switched to slideUp for better visuals

```js
$(function() {
  $(".expand").on( "click", function() {
    if ($(this).find(".right-arrow").text() === "-") {
      return;
    }

    $(".detail").slideUp();
    $(".right-arrow").text("+");
    
    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");
    
    if($expand.text() == "+") {
      $expand.text("-");
    } else {
      $expand.text("+");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#integration-list {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#integration-list ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #555;
}
#integration-list ul > li {
    list-style: none;
/*    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;*/
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#integration-list ul > li > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.expand {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expand h2{
    font-size: 28px;
}
#sup{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
}
.detail {
    margin: 0 34px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 22px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
}

.detail h2{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
.right-arrow {
/*    margin-top: 12px;*/
    margin:0 20px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.icon {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

<div id="integration-list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>
        </li>
        
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            </a>

            <div class="detail">
                
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sagittis risus non tellus viverra suscipit. Integer eu vehicula orci, vel semper tortor. Cras ultrices semper vestibulum. Aliquam luctus euismod urna, vitae tincidunt lectus porta id. Nulla porttitor feugiat nisi posuere porta. Curabitur vitae nibh vitae nunc lobortis eleifend. Nullam feugiat urna vitae augue molestie finibus. Nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
               
         </div>        
     </li>


    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `slideUp()` will be more suitable than `hide()` though :)

Comment: Whatever he feels like using. What I meant to explain was he needs to hide all before expanding any. But  I will implement your suggestion

Comment: Yeah, its just that he used `slideToggle()` so it will be better with `slideUp`

Comment: Also realised the + needs to be set too

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Anurag. it's working but have you checked my Script? Because when I clicked on current accordion which is open that will also close. And your script is closing another accordion which is opened.

Comment: Oh, did you mean you don't want the current accordion to close and then reopen? that is a little issue indeed but it can be fixed too

Comment: I updated the code to ignore clicks on open panels. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: If you don't want a single panel to be open at all times, sahil's answer would be better. Mine will always keep at least one panel open, if you need that.

Comment: Thanks for your help  Mr.Anurag, You code is  Working perfectly for me in another project. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 1):

Please see below code. +(collapse) and -(expand) working properly.

```
$(function() {
  $(".expand").on( "click", function() {
    $(".detail").hide();
    $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");

    if($expand.text() == "+") {
      $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
      $(".expand").find(">:first-child").text("+");
      $expand.text("-");
    } else {
      $expand.text("+");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Narendra. Please check now

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Ganesh, Your code is working for me  but not that much which I want.. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $("#accordion > li > span").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('span').removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp(250);
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next('div').slideToggle(250);
});
```

```css
#accordion {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 2px;
}
#accordion > li {
 display: block;
 list-style: none;
}
#accordion > li > span {
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 4px 0;
 padding: 6px;
 background: url(images/expand_arrow.png) no-repeat 99.5% 6px #525252;
 background-size: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 cursor: pointer; font-size:16px
}
#accordion > li > div {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 6px;
 display: none; overflow:auto
}
#accordion > ul li {
 font-weight: normal;
 cursor: auto;
 padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
#accordion a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion li > span:hover {
}
#accordion li > span.active {
 background: url(images/collapse-arrow.png) no-repeat 99.5% 6px #000;
 background-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion">
  <li><span>Tab 1</span>
    <div>
tab1
    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Tab 2</span>
    <div>
   Tab 3
    </div>
    
  </li>
  
  <li><span>tab 3</span>
    <div>
  tab 3
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li><span>tab 4</span>
    <div>
Tab 4
      </div>  

    
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

the is another way to achive it but @Anurag Daolagajao already make corrections into your code